# Kubernetes/Openshift Statefulset example: cannot find volume plugin for alpha provisioning

Tags: openshift, kubernetes

I'm trying to run this [Zookeeper Openshift example](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/statefulsets/zookeeper) or the equivalent [kubernetes one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper/), but I end with errors such as:

```
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------   --------        ------                  -------
  1h            12s             281     {default-scheduler }                    Warning         FailedScheduling        [SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "datadir-zoo-0", which is unexpected., SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "datadir-zoo-0", which is unexpected.]
```

or

```
error finding provisioning plugin for claim test/datadir-zoo-2: cannot find volume plugin for alpha provisioning
```

Here is my openshift [template.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Syffs/0ddf5f007ca8360f3ac50262697e6452)

I'm note sure but I suspect that it might be due to line `volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything`, because I don't think that there is any default StorageClass defined...
If so how can I set up the most simple StorageClass to get this to work, because as I'm self-hosting my openshift origin cluster, I cannot fit into any of the cloud storage option (GCE, AWS, Azure, etc...)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it actually is more related to the setup of storage on your cluster.

There are several storage options as mentioned at [OpenShift Origin: Persistent Storage](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/additional_concepts/storage.html)

If you run it locally, you could use `NFS` (see [OpenShift Origin: Persistent Storage using NFS](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_nfs.html)).

If you run it in minishift or single node cluster, you can use `HostPath` (see [Minishift Persistent Volumes](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/blob/master/docs/using.md#persistent-volumes)). In this case it would be enough to create a PersistentVolume of size 1GB. Then the PersistentVolumeClaim in your template can be bound.